# F# Query Expression "The field, constructor or member 'Contains' is not defined"

Tags: f#, query-expressions

I'm trying to get this example from the Query Expressions page to work. I've got the database setup and I've made many small bits of code work.

```
    let idQuery = query { for id in [1; 2; 5; 10] do
                  select id }

    query { 
       for student in db.Student do
       where (idQuery.Contains(student.StudentID))
       select student
    }
```

But all I get is the error:

> The field, constructor or member 'Contains' is not defined

What am I missing? I've got other examples to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I needed to have the `System.Linq` namespace imported.